# convert query result to dictionary in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, dictionary

What is the proper syntax for .ToDictionary to return the following as a Dictionary(Of String, String) where ShortDesc is the key and CurrentFrontSymbol is the value

```
 Dim dicQuery As Dictionary(Of String, String) = (From d In toolkitEntities.currentfrontcommoditysymbols
                                                     Select d.ShortDesc, d.CurrentFrontSymbol)
```

**Update**

And can the following functions query and following For Each loop become one LINQ query?

```
Public Shared Function GetRangeProjectionPerformance(Optional daysToRetrieve As Integer = 100) As Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of ProjectionPerformance))

    Dim todaysDate As Date = DateTime.Now.Date
    Dim lookbackDate As Date = todaysDate.AddDays(daysToRetrieve * -1)
    Dim temp As New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of ProjectionPerformance))


    Using ctx As New ProjectionsEntities()
        Dim query = (From d In ctx.projections
                     Where d.SymbolId <= 42 AndAlso d.Date >= lookbackDate
                     Join t In ctx.symbols On d.SymbolId Equals t.Id
                     Let actualRange = d.HighProjection - d.LowProjection
                     Select New With {
                        d.Date,
                        d.SymbolId,
                        t.Name,
                        actualRange}).GroupBy(Function(o) o.SymbolId).ToDictionary(Function(p) p.Key)

        For Each itm In query
            Dim rpp As New ProjectionPerformance
            Dim rppList As New List(Of ProjectionPerformance)
            If itm.Value.Count > 0 Then
                For x As Integer = 0 To itm.Value.Count - 1
                    Dim bb As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(itm.Value(x).SymbolId)
                    With rpp
                        .SymbolId = bb
                        .ProjectionDate = itm.Value(x).Date.ToString()
                        .Name = itm.Value(x).Name
                        .ProjectedRange = itm.Value(x).actualRange
                    End With
                    rppList.Add(rpp)
                Next
            End If

            temp.Add(itm.Key, rppList)
        Next
    End Using
    Return temp
End Function
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you do not have a special projection in the select, you can just call `ToDictionary` on the collection. The first lambda expression retrieves the key, the second one the value.

```
Dim dicQuery = toolkitEntities.currentfrontcommoditysymbols.ToDictionary( _
                   Function(x) x.ShortDesc, _
                   Function(y) y.CurrentFrontSymbol)
```

As for your update: the following query should get you the desired result:

```
Dim query = (From d In ctx.projections
             Where d.SymbolId <= 42 AndAlso d.Date >= lookbackDate
             Join t In ctx.symbols On d.SymbolId Equals t.Id
             Let actualRange = d.HighProjection - d.LowProjection
             Select New With {
                d.Date,
                d.SymbolId,
                t.Name,
                actualRange}).GroupBy(Function(o) o.SymbolId)
            .ToDictionary(Function(p) p.Key, 
                          Function(x) x.Select(Function(y) New ProjectionPerformance() With {
                              .SymbolId = Convert.ToInt32(y.SymbolId), 
                              .ProjectionDate = y.Date.ToString(), 
                              .Name = y.Name, 
                              .ProjectedRange = y.actualRange
                          }).ToList())
```

Comment: Thank you, I just couldnt get it right. Can I trouble you to look at my update in the post. I m sure that function can utilize one LINQ query versus how I am accomplishing it.

Comment: @dinotom: You're welcome. Good to hear that it helped. As for your update: depends on what you want to accomplish. Does the code work now? I suspect that you end up having the same list for each key in `temp` at the end as you do not create a new list for each run of the `For Each`. If you want to have a new list for each key, you'd have to add another parameter to the 1st `ToDictionary` that creates a list.

Comment: @dinotom: I've updated my post. Hope that it helps. You might consider creating a new question for that in order to other users also taking notice of the new content.

Comment: @Markus...ty it works and cut the average time from 5500 milliseconds to just under 2000 milliseconds. As to my prior it works as expected. In the code I had the rpplist in the for each loop. don't know how it ended up up top when i copied it over to the post ( i copied it in chunks)

Comment: @Markus...It actually doesn't work. I've posted it as a new question

Comment: Here is the link to the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084241/mscorlib-error-on-linq