# mscorlib error on LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am getting an InvalidOperation on mscorlib.dll error on the following query and cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Here is the Class I'm populating the List(Of ) with;

```
Public Class ProjectionPerformance
    Public SymbolId As Long
    Public Name As String
    Public ProjectionDate As String
    Public ActualRange As Double
    Public ProjectedRange As Double
End Class
```

Those types match the types in the table except for the date which I convert to a string

Here is the function with the LINQ query

```
  Public Shared Function GetRangeProjectionPerformance(Optional daysToRetrieve As Integer = 100) As Dictionary(Of Long, List(Of ProjectionPerformance))

    Dim todaysDate As Date = DateTime.Now.Date
    Dim lookbackDate As Date = todaysDate.AddDays(daysToRetrieve * -1)

    Using ctx As New ProjectionsEntities

        Dim query = (From d In ctx.projections
                    Where d.SymbolId <= 42 AndAlso d.Date >= lookbackDate
                    Join t In ctx.symbols On d.SymbolId Equals t.Id
                    Let actualRange = d.ActualHigh - d.ActualLow
                    Let projectedRange = d.HighProjection - d.LowProjection
                    Select New With {
                    d.Date,
                    d.SymbolId,
                    t.Name,
                    projectedRange,
                    actualRange}).GroupBy(Function(o) o.SymbolId).ToDictionary(Function(p) p.Key,
                                Function(x) x.Select(Function(y) New ProjectionPerformance() With {
                                    .SymbolId = y.SymbolId,
                                    .ProjectionDate = y.Date.ToString(),
                                    .Name = y.Name,
                                    .ActualRange = y.actualRange,
                                    .ProjectedRange = y.projectedRange
                                }).ToList())


        Return query
    End Using
End Function
```

I'm getting that error on this part of the LINQ query (Im assuming that is that portion is highlighted in green in VS2013)

```
 Function(x) x.Select(Function(y) New ProjectionPerformance() With {
```

Do I have to retrieve the actual field values and eliminate the Let statements and do the calcs in the List function of the Dictionary call?

Comment: What is the exact error message of the `InvalidOperationException`?

Comment: A first chance exception of type System.InvalidOperationException occured in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Is there an InnerException with a more detailed message? Does it help if you change `Function(y) New Proj...` to `Function(y) y` (not that this is the desired result, but in order to find the error)?

Comment: there is no more detail. Ill try the change to see if it gets more detail

Comment: Actually under the mscorlib error it says Additional Information: Nullable object must have a value....Thats stemming from the fact that some dates may have nulls in their actual high and actual low values if those markets were closed for a holiday or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I suspect that the problem is that you try to assign null values to the double properties in `ProjectionPerformance`. It should work if you change your code as follows:

```
Dim query = (From d In ctx.projections
                Where d.SymbolId <= 42 AndAlso d.Date >= lookbackDate
                Join t In ctx.symbols On d.SymbolId Equals t.Id
                Let actualRange = d.ActualHigh - d.ActualLow
                Let projectedRange = d.HighProjection - d.LowProjection
                Select New With {
                d.Date,
                d.SymbolId,
                t.Name,
                projectedRange,
                actualRange}).GroupBy(Function(o) o.SymbolId).ToDictionary(Function(p) p.Key,
                            Function(x) x.Select(Function(y) New ProjectionPerformance() With {
                                .SymbolId = y.SymbolId,
                                .ProjectionDate = y.Date.ToString(),
                                .Name = y.Name,
                                .ActualRange = If(y.actualRange, 0.0),
                                .ProjectedRange = y.projectedRange
                            }).ToList())
```

In order to spot such errors before running the program, you should set OPTION STRICT to ON (either on project or file level).

Comment: yes,with option strict on it doesnt like >ActualRange = y.ActualHigh - y.ActualLow....and thats because some of those have null values...testing your update now

Comment: Is there a way to make the Let projectedRange statement nullable? as im getting that error. "First operand in a binary If expression must be nullable or reference type. Those fields in the table are currently not nullable

Comment: @dinotom: if the projectedRange is not nullable, I'd rather remove the `If` and make `If(y.projectedRange, 0.0)` to just `y.projectedRange`. I've just added that for consistency, but it's better if it isn't nullable in the first place.

Comment: There wasnt a real use case for it to be not nullable so i changed the fields to nullable....all good now